# scrapy python project does not export data to excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, scrapy

my script is below, first it reads `plate_num_xlsx` value from excel file `data.xlsx` successfully then requests scrapy to scrape data from url. At each parse() invocation, I am taking values parsed to `item` then trying to export them to excel with pandas.

```
        if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
            item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
        else:
            item = {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": "-"}

    df_output=pd.DataFrame([item],columns=["PLATE","PRICE"])
    df_output.to_excel("output_res.xlsx",sheet_name="result",index=False,header=True)
```

Excel file `output_res.xlsx` has been created successfully. But parsed data in item is not being exported to (written to) that file. What can be issue?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd

class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
                item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": "-"}
                
        df_output=pd.DataFrame([item],columns=["PLATE","PRICE"])
        df_output.to_excel("output_res.xlsx",sheet_name="result",index=False,header=True)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of dictionary `item` are used as columns of your new `pd.DataFrame`. [As per pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), providing columns to `pd.DataFrame` names columns by provided column names **if data doesn't have column names already**, and if data does contain column names (as it does in your case), it uses column names from pd.DataFrame method to do a column select.

As you don't have dictionary items named "PLATE" or "PRICE", the resulting dataframe is empty.

So, skip providing column names in `pd.DataFrame`, and if you want to rename them, do so after creating the dataframe.

```
df_output=pd.DataFrame([item])
df_output.columns = ["PLATE","PRICE"]
```

Comment: it seems like it overwrites data on each iteration. But I need to write it each time under old one

Comment: You overwrite `item` on each iteration, only creating a dataframe from the last result. You could create an empty list before the `for` loop, and then append each item to it. Then, creating DataFrame only pass that list (you'd do something like `pd.DataFrame(item_list)` instead of `pd.DataFrame([item])`

Comment: I guess, itemDict dictionary I need to create not list, isn't? because I have 'plate' and 'price' as key-column values

Comment: The dictionary `item` is fine, you just need to have a list of all `item` dicts that you create in the `for` loop (currently you discard all but the last `item` dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

The allowed_domains variable is set to `'dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk'` but the URLs being accessed are on `'dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk'`. This might cause issues as Scrapy will only follow links within the specified domain.

The parse method is overwriting the output excel file with each iteration, so only the last item will be present in the output file.

The code would fail to run because the yield `scrapy.Request(url)` should be yield `scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)`

You are using global keyword to define a variable which is not required here. It can be defined as a instance variable.

It would also be best to use a unique name for the output file to avoid overwriting any existing files.

Comment: yes parse() method overwrites data on each iteration, I would like to change it. It works without scrapy.Request(url, `self.parse`). If I do not declare it global variable, it does not see it in other function. Then I need to pass it as parameter I guess